# Is it possible to make generic child classes see different interface of same variable in c#

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

Let me describe a simplified story on this. I try to design a recommend function, it will recommend you different product by different match rules.

```cs
// TV will match a product by given TV related parameters

public class TvMatcher
{
    public Product Match(ITvMatchParam tvMatchParam)
    {
        return new Product(); // pick a tv by tvMatchParam
    }
}

public interface ITvMatchParam
{
    int Age { get; }
    int Gender { get; }
}
```

```cs
// Phone will match a product by given Phone related parameters

public class PhoneMatcher
{
    Product Match(IPhoneMatchParam phoneMatchParam)
    {
        return new Product(); // pick a phone by phoneMatchParam
    }
}

public interface IPhoneMatchParam
{
    int Age { get; }
    int Education { get; }
}
```

The `Recommend` here is a public API which accept a union parameters.
Then it will pick a Matcher and call match() to pick a product.

```cs
public class Main
{
    public Product Recommend(AllMatchParams allParams)
    {
        // pseudo code here, can't compile
        IMatcher matcher = CreateMatcherFactoryMethod(allParams);
        return matcher.Match(allParams);
    }

    private static IMatcher CreateMatcherFactoryMethod(AllMatchParams allParams)
    {
        IMatcher matcher;
        if (allParams.Product == 0)
        {
            matcher = new TvMatcher();
        }
        else
        {
            matcher = new PhoneMatcher();
        }

        return matcher;
    }
}

class AllMatchParams : ITvMatchParam, IPhoneMatchParam
{
    public int Age { get; }
    public int Education { get; }
    public int Gender { get; }
    public int Product { get; }
}
```

But above code won't be compiled because TvMatcher and PhoneMatcher cannot implement IMatcher

```cs
public interface IMatcher
{
    Product Match(AllMatchParams allMatchParams);
}
```

Since TvMatcher only cares Tv related parameters, PhoneMatcher only cares PhoneMatcher related parameters, I don't want to force PhoneMatcher implment IMatcher.

```cs
public class PhoneMatcher: IMatcher
{
    Product Match(AllMatchParams allParams)
    {
        // don't like this because PhoneMatcher only cares subset properties in allParams
    }
}
```

So I try to implement an AbstractClass and make PhoneMatcher inherit it. I hope it can accept a AllMatchParams and only see PhoneMatchParam in implementation.

```cs
public abstract class AbstractMatcher<TProductMatchParam>: IMatcher
{
    public Product Match(AllMatchParams allMatchParams)
    {
        return ProductMatch(allMatchParams);  // fails here
    }

    protected abstract Product ProductMatch(TProductMatchParam param);
}

public class PhoneMatcher: AbstractMatcher<IPhoneMatchParam>
{
    protected Product ProductMatch(IPhoneMatchParam phoneMatchParam)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
public class TvMatcher: AbstractMatcher<ITvMatchParam>
{
    protected Product ProductMatch(ITvMatchParam tvMatchParam)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But above code won't compile because AllMatchParams cannot cast to generic variable `<TProductMatchParam>`.

Is there a way to make AbstractMatcher.Match can accept a fixed type parameter and delegate to child, so child can see different interfaces of that parameter?

I had tried to add constraints to generic variable but fail because cannot make TProductMatchParam constraint to either `IPhoneMatchParam` or `ITvMatchParam` at same time.

Answer (score 2):

Your `AbstractMatcher` is a bit too much

You could make your `IMatcher` interface generic instead :

```
public interface IMatcher<T>
{
    Product Match(T matchParam);
}

public class PhoneMatcher: IMatcher<IPhoneMatchParam>
{
    public Product Match(IPhoneMatchParam matchParam)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public class TvMatcher: IMatcher<ITvMatchParam>
{
    public Product Match(ITvMatchParam matchParam)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In this case you can pass your `AllMatchParams` instance in the 2 methods.

```
return new PhoneMatcher().Match(criteria) ?? new TvMatcher().Match(criteria);
```

Will returns the first not null matched product

Comment: But with IMatcher<T> interface, I can only use factory method with Generic. I cannot return same `IMatcher` in factory method.
```
    private static IMatcher CreateMatcherFactoryMethod(AllMatchParams allParams)
    {
        IMatcher matcher;
        if (allParams.Product == 0)
        {
            matcher = new TvMatcher();
        }
        else
        {
            matcher = new PhoneMatcher();
        }

        return matcher;
    }
```

Comment: Your factory method just returning one instance based on criteria of your research. Why do you need a factory ?